# How to set a value in session in cherrypy and how to get that value?

Tags: python, session, odoo, cherrypy

I have created a session as the following by importing cherrypy

```
cherrypy.session['otp_status']=1
```

But when I try to retrieve it as the following

```
otp_status=cherrypy.session['otp_status']
```

It shows

```
KeyError: 'otp_status'
```

How to get the value from session ?

Comment: `cherrypy.session['otp_status']==1` is a comparison, not assigning.

Comment: Are you sure you did not type `cherrypy.session['otp_status'] = 1` instead?

Comment: @Cthulhu I have updated the question. I am trying to retrieve the session value from another python file. And the KeyError: 'otp_status'  occurs there.

Answer (score 0):

[Are you sure that you server time is accurate?.](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/refman/lib/sessions.html?highlight=sessions#expiration-dates)